# How can I make the GtkSource.View adapt to the dark mode?

Tags: gtk, gnome

I'm facing the problem that `GtkSource.View` does not change the theme based on the user's selected theme (light/dark mode). Here is a screenshot: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LhhK.png).

Interestingly, this works perfectly fine with `Gtk.TextView`. How can I make it work with `GtkSource.View` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Gtk.SourceView** has its own color scheme controlled by **GtkSource.StyleScheme**. If you want a dark theme look, you have to create a theme and apply it manually.

**Gtk.SourceView** is not built on **libadwaita**, which implements the dark theme in Gnome.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought it would adapt to the dark theme look as it is AFAIK based on `Gtk.TextView` which does adapt to the dark theme. But as theming is more than just light/dark in a `GtkSource.View`, that makes sense. Thank you very much!